# Have you used online participant recruitment services such as Prolific and MTurk? Which service do you use?

Tags: research-process

I am looking to get feedback from people who have used online participant recruitment services such as Prolific and MTurk for participant recruitment. We have been using MTurk, but I am looking to get feedback about alternatives.

Comment: please provide additional context for people to be able to answer your question. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: Recruitment for what, exactly?

Comment: I support labs who use these tools and some others for human subject payments but what is your concern?  I believe my researchers choose them for different types of experiments. They work in HCI.  I'm not sure why, but people seem to be moving away from MTurk and towards Prolific.  I would try setting if folks in the field of HCI can offer perspective.  There may be background given in their publications about which service they chose. Use these sites as keywords in Google Scholar and you should get some interesting things.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Prolific in the past and would highly recommend it. The participants are screened carefully and they tend to ban spam accounts quickly. I'm not sure what time of participants you are seeking to recruit for your study, but they do screen users based on how they answer demographic questions as a means of trying to get more accurate feedback for studies.